About Durret's proof of Wald’s second equation
In Durret's Probability Theories and Examples (4th edition), the last step to prove Wald’s second equation is using the results (The full question and proof is attached here) is:
\begin{align}
ES_{T\wedge n}^2=\sigma^2\sum_{m=1}^nP(T\geq m)\\E(S_{T\wedge n}-S_{T\wedge m})^2=\sigma^2\sum_{k=m+1}^nP(T\geq n)
\end{align}
where $T$ is stopping time, $S_n$ is random walk at step $n$. Then the second equality implies $S_{T\wedge n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2$. By this, Durret claims: with $n\to\infty$, it follows $ES_T=\sigma^2\sum_{m=1}^\infty P(T\ge m)$.
My question is: why is the final claim right?

Could you clarify what the notation $T \wedge n$ means?

@mathperson314 it means $\min(T,n)$

In the second equation $P(T\geq n)
$ should be $P(T\geq k)
$

$ES_T=\sigma^2\sum_{m=1}^\infty P(T\ge m)$ also has  typo.

As to the final claim $ES_T=\sigma^2\sum_{m=1}^\infty P(T\ge m)$: Because $(S_{T\wedge n})_{n\ge 1}$ is Cauchy in $L^2$, it is $L^2$ convergence to some random variable $Y$. But also, $\lim_n S_{T\wedge n}=S_T$ on the event $\{T<\infty\}$, hence almost surely. Because a subsequence of $(S_{T\wedge n})_{n\ge 1}$ converges a.s., we must have $Y=S_T$ a.s. Thus $\lim_n S_{T\wedge n} =S_T$ in $L^2$; in particular, $\|S_T\|_2^2 =\lim_n\|S_{T\wedge n}\|_2^2$. Finally,
$$
E[S_T^2]=\lim_nE[S_{T\wedge n}^2]=\lim_n\sigma^2\sum_{m=1}^n P[T\ge m]=\sigma^2\sum_{m=1}^\infty P[T\ge m].
$$

Let $Y_n:=S^2_{\min\{n,T\}}$. We know that $Y_n\to S_T^2$ almost surely and
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[(S_{\min\{n,T\}}-S_{\min\{m,T\}})^2\right]=\sigma^2\sum_{k=m+1}^nP(T\geqslant k)
\end{align}
combined with $$\lVert Y_m-Y_n\rVert_1=\mathbb E\left[\lvert\left(S_{\min\{m,T\}}-S_{\min\{n,T\}}\right)\left(S_{\min\{m,T\}}+S_{\min\{n,T\}}\right)\rvert\right]$$
implies that $(Y_n)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb L^1$. Therefore, $Y_n\to S_T^2$ in $\mathbb L^1$ and the result follows.

Assuming that $\sigma^2<\infty$, observe that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}T=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb{P}(T>n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(T\geq n).
\end{equation}
Now $T\geq 0$ almost surely and $\mathbb{E}T<\infty$ and so for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $\sum_{n\geq N}\mathbb{P}(T\geq n)\leq\varepsilon$, which implies that it is Cauchy. Hence, putting all together yields that for each $\varepsilon'>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(S_{n\wedge T}-S_{m\wedge T})^2=\sigma^2\sum_{k=m+1}^n\mathbb{P}(T\geq m)\leq\sigma^2\varepsilon'
\end{equation}
whenever $N\leq m<n$. Take $\varepsilon=\varepsilon'/\sigma^2$ to get the Cauchy property. From this you can also deduct that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}S_{n\wedge T}^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma^2\sum_{m=1}^n\mathbb{P}(T\geq m)=\sigma^2\mathbb{E}T.
\end{equation}

I think OP's question is mainly about how one can indeed deduce that $\lim_nE[S_{T\wedge n}^2]=E[S_T^2]$.
